# LINQ: Assign Event handler in Select creation

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ statement which creates a number of items

```
From x in datasource
   select (Customer) new BusinessCustomer(x.SomeThing)
```

I need to set the BusinessCustomer.OnTapped event handler.

Can this be done in the LINQ statement?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807797/linq-select-an-object-and-change-some-properties-without-creating-a-new-object

Comment: No it can't and shouldn't.  Write a loop.  Add helper methods.  Whatever.  LINQ should be used for performing queries, not modifying things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the `BusinessCustomer` class, you could add a constructor that accepts a handler delegate for the `OnTapped` event.

If you can't or don't want to modify `BusinessCustomer` to do this, you could use a helper method, which would also allow you to eliminate the cast.

```
private Customer CreateBusinessCustomer(Thing thing, EventHandler tapHandler)
{
    var customer = new BusinessCustomer(thing);
    customer.OnTapped = tapHandler;
    return customer;
}

private void Customer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Now your query looks like:

```
from x in datasource
select CreateBusinessCustomer(x.SomeThing, Customer_OnTapped)
```