# First() for HtmlElementCollection

Tags: c#, browser, ref

I wrote a method-extension for to simualte List's [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.90).aspx) but the returned value (actually reference, isn't?) doesn't work if I try to change a property of it, for example;

```
HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("foo").First();
ele.InnerText = "hello!"; // doesn't Works. That value isn't changed. Why?
webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("foo")[0].InnerText = "abc"; // but this does Works
```

Here's `First()` function:

```
   public static HtmlElement First(this HtmlElementCollection a)
        {
            if (a == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            if (a.Count == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return a[0];
        }
```

Why using return from `a.First().value = foo` doesn't Works but `arr[0].value = "hehe";` does? how do I fix it? do I need to learn how to use returns `ref`?

Comment: you can test if the result from First() and [0] is the same reference, they should be same, HtmlElement is a Class, so the instance of it is on the heap, doesn't make sence they don't equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this post: [LINQ: Select an object and change some properties without creating a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807797/linq-select-an-object-and-change-some-properties-without-creating-a-new-object)

```
var ele = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("foo")
                              .First().Select(e => { e.InnerText = "hello"; return e; });
```