# How to match two Lists with only items that are different in Linq

Tags: linq

I have a `StudentData` class

```
public class StudentData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Bonus { get; set; }
    public int? Subject1Mark { get; set; }
    public int? Subject2Mark { get; set; }
    public int? Subject3Mark{ get; set; }
}
```

Each student has a unique `Id` that identifies him

I have a `List<StudentData> CurrentData` that has data of

> 1, John, Smith, 10, 50 ,50 ,50
>
> 2, Peter, Parker, 10, 60 ,60 ,60
>
> 3, Sally, Smart, 10, 70 ,70 ,70
>
> 4, Danny, Darko, 20, 80, 80, 80

I then have a `List<StudentData> DataToUpdate` which only contains the `Id` and Marks fields. Not the other fields.

> 1, null, null, null, 50 ,50 ,50
>
> 2, null, null, null, 65, 60 ,60
>
> 3, null, null, null, 70 ,70 ,70

The Ids of the list are not necessary in the same order

If you compare the two lists only Peter Parker's marks have changed in one subject.

I want to get the output to return

> 2, Peter, Parker, 10, 65 ,60 ,60

I want to take`List<StudentData> CurrentData` inner join this with `List<StudentData> DataToUpdate` but only where marks are different

So in SQL it want the following

```
SELECT
CurrentData.Id,
CurrentData.FirstName ,
CurrentData.Surname,
CurrentData.Bonus,
DataToUpdate.Subject1Mark,
DataToUpdate.Subject2Mark,
DataToUpdate.Subject3Mark
FROM CurrentData
INNER JOIN DataToUpdate
ON CurrentData.Id= DataToUpdate.Id
AND (
    CurrentData.Subject1Mark<> DataToUpdate.Subject1Mark
    OR
    CurrentData.Subject2Mark<> DataToUpdate.Subject2Mark
    OR
    CurrentData.Subject3Mark<> DataToUpdate.Subject3Mark
)
```

How do I do the above in LINQ?

In the Linq `select` how do I take all properties from `CurrentData` but include the 3 Subject properties from `DataToUpdate` in it to give me `List<ChangedData>`?

I could map each and every property but my StudentData has 100 fields and I would prefer to have something like

```
select new StudentData {
    this=CurrentData,
    this.Subject1Mark=DataToUpdate.Subject1Mark,
    this.Subject2Mark=DataToUpdate.Subject2Mark,
    this.Subject3Mark=DataToUpdate.Subject3Mark,
}
```

but I'm not sure how to write this

There is an answer in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807797/linq-select-an-object-and-change-some-properties-without-creating-a-new-object) which should work but it doesn't. If I implement that solution (I simplify the example for simplicity)

```
        var changedData = currentData
             .Join(dataToUpdate, cd => cd.Id, ld => ld.Id, (cd, ld) => new { cd, ld })
             .Select(x => { x.cd.Subject1Mark= x.ld.Subject1Mark; return x.cd; })
             ;
```

but the above  `x.cd.Subject1Mark` isn't updated by `x.ld.Subject1Mark` although I use the answer in the linked stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of LINQ query looks very similar to SQL:

```
var res =
    from cur in CurrentData
    join upd in DataToUpdate on upd.Id equals cur.Id
    where (cur.Subject1Mark != upd.Subject1Mark || cur.Subject2Mark != upd.Subject2Mark || cur.Subject3Mark != upd.Subject3Mark)
    select new {
        Current = cur
    ,   UpdatedSubject1Mark = upd.Subject1Mark
    ,   UpdatedSubject2Mark = upd.Subject2Mark
    ,   UpdatedSubject3Mark = upd.Subject3Mark
    };
```

The main difference is that filtering out by inequality has moved from the `on` clause in SQL to a `where` clause of LINQ.

Comment: In the `select` how do I take all properties from `cur` but include the 3 Subject properties from `upd` in it?

Comment: Problem is I need the output to be of type  List<StudentData> because I need to write it to the database using the original object type.  If I make it like in your answer I get error `Cannot convert IEnumerable anonymous type to Generic.List<StudentData>

Comment: @devc2 You can't produce `StudentData` from `{StudentData+three more fields}`, unless you would like to replace the old data with whatever is in the `upd`, in which case you do `select new StudentData {Id=cur.Id, FirstName=cur.FirstName, ..., UpdatedSubject1Mark = upd.UpdatedSubject1Mark, UpdatedSubject2Mark = upd.UpdatedSubject3Mark, ...}`