# How to join the result of one query into the result of another without selecting new instance?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class where it's data comes from two difference sources - one is a database and the other is a web API.
The database source gives me most of the data, and the web API just a few properties.
I get the data from the database using Dapper, as an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` (where the properties from the web API are all nulls),
and the data from the web API is an `IEnumerable<WebApiClass>`.

Now I need to join these two results to a single `IEnuemrable<MyClass>` - simple enough -

```
var query = from c in dbResults
            join w in webResults on c.Id equals w.Id
            select new MyClass()
            {
                dbProp1 = c.dbProp1, dbProp2 = c.dbProp2, ...
                waProp1 = w.Prop1, waProp2 = w.Prop2, ...
            }
```

Is there a way to do that without selecting a `new MyClass()`, but simply use the already existing instances of `MyClass` from `dbResults`?

All the join queries I've seen use `select new` - is that really the only option?

Comment: I think your question can be worded a little differently, because what you really want is to `select c` with updated properties based on `w`-- Which has [already been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/807797/2679750)

Comment: @MarkC. Thanks, I did try rephrasing my search, but that one just didn't came up.

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method syntax join and explicitly open the scope of the `resultSelector`. In it edit the object as you want and return it.

```
var result = dbResults.Join(webResults, db => db.Id, web => web.Id
                            (db, web) => {
                                db.SomePropFromWeb = web.SomeProp;
                                return db;
                            });
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check both the dupe and your answer tomorrow and accept if I can make it work.