# How to return objects by updating few properties in linq query that uses JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I know this question has been asked many times however LINQ itself seems confusing sometimes. And I really needed to understand how to utilize LINQ and what happens inside.

My sample project contains following entities:
Movies, Entities, MovieEntitiesLink

Is there a way in C# LINQ query using which I can update properties right when the object is projected to output list ?

Sample code:

```
var finalResult = (from me in MovieEntitiesLink
                  join m in Movies on me.MovieId equals m.Id
                  join e in Entities on me.EntityId equals e.Id
                  //me => me.Movie = m, me.Entity = e
                  select me);
```

Edit : The answer linked here for duplicate was a bit confusing however the most original question for which all these questions were marked duplicate, did the job for me.

Comment: A duplicate of a duplicate :-)

Comment: Thanks for marking it duplicate but I really need help to understand what happened in that linked answer. The syntax shown in the answer of the linked article does not work in my case.

Comment: You can use query syntax with `let` as [shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15552013/3094533)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried that too, it does not work instead shows error "An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator"

Comment: @ZoharPeled Wait I had not converted it to list, I will update once i run and it works. Thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks it worked.